# Need the object name that is producing the error within a try catch block of an sql server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, error-handling

I create a stored procedure that updates the structure of a database.  Within the try/catch block if an error occurs I can get the ERROR_MESSAGE() value but it does not specify where the error occurred or on what object.  The ERROR_NUMBER() function is useless because the line numbers are off ab a lot.

Is there anyway to identify the object that was being created or the statement that it failed on?
Below is a small example of a try catch block:

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Activity] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Activity_dbo.Application_ApplicationId] FOREIGN KEY ([ApplicationId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Application] ([ApplicationId]) ON DELETE CASCADE 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Activity] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Activity_dbo.Application_ApplicationId] 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationCategory] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ApplicationCategory_Application] FOREIGN KEY ([ApplicationId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Application] ([ApplicationId]) 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationCategory] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ApplicationCategory_Application] 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contacts] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Contacts_Product] FOREIGN KEY ([ProductId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Product] ([ProductId]) 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contacts] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Contacts_Product] 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Frame] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Frame_dbo.Product_ProductId] FOREIGN KEY ([ProductId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Product] ([ProductId]) 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Frame] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Frame_dbo.Product_ProductId] 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FramesMarkup] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.FramesMarkup_dbo.Manufacturer_ManufacturerId] FOREIGN KEY ([ManufacturerId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Manufacturer] ([ManufacturerId]) 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FramesMarkup] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.FramesMarkup_dbo.Manufacturer_ManufacturerId] 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[InventoryDecrement] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.InventoryDecrement_dbo.Inventory_InventoryId] FOREIGN KEY ([InventoryId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Inventory] ([InventoryId]) 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[InventoryDecrement] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.InventoryDecrement_dbo.Inventory_InventoryId] 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Lens] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Lens_dbo.Rx_RxId] FOREIGN KEY ([RxId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Rx] ([RxId]) ON DELETE CASCADE 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Lens] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Lens_dbo.Rx_RxId] 

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

The error message is: `Could not create constraint. See previous errors.`
I would like to know which constraint failed.

Comment: The function ERROR_LINE() might help you here.

Comment: If you have multiple failures you'll only catch the first

Comment: That's OK.  Let me try ERROR_LINE() - this will give the line number?

Comment: I tried creating constraint with the repro script,it gives me clear message `Msg 4902, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Cannot find the object "dbo.Activity" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.`

Comment: The ERROR_LINE() is good.  It gives me the correct line number.  This script is part of a larger stored procedure.  When the table creation fails, it returns good error messaging. But of the contraints created, it gives the above error.

Comment: @pmbAustin - Create an answer with the Error_line() so I can check it answered...thanks.

Comment: @GloriaSantin Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function ERROR_LINE() might help you here. It returns the line number of where the script error occurred.  You can use that as long as the script isn't being constantly edited, causing the line number to move around.

Answer (score 0):

The error functions I use to log errors are, error_number, error_severity, error_state, error_line, error_procedure, error_message.

With that said, if you want to know the constraint that failed, I would create a parameter for it and before every constraint update it with the constraint name.  Then print that in your catch.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `@step int = 0` variable in the beginning of `try` block.

And increment it for every constraint.
Then output it in `catch` block.